# Ensure Symfony2 Entity Property Type Is Correct After Retrieving From Database

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, entity

I have a Symfony2 entity that has a non-scalar property of a given class type. The property can be cast safely to a string and this is how it is persisted in the database.

When an instance of this entity is retrieved from the database, the getter for the property returns a string instead of an object of the expected class.

Here is a generic example entity:

```
<?php
namespace Acme\ExampleBundle\Entity;    

class ExampleEntity
{    
    /**
     * @var \example\ComplexObject
     * @\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $property;        

    /**
     * @param \example\ComplexObject $property
     * @return \ExampleEntity 
     */
    public function setProperty(\example\ComplexObject $property) {
        $this->property = $property;
        return $this;
    }        

    /**
     * @return \example\ComplexObject
     */
    public function getProperty() {
        return $this->property;
    }        
}
```

To be clear, calling `getProperty()` on an instance of this entity after retrieval from the database returns a string and not an instance of `\example\ComplexObject`.

I appreciate that Symfony and/or Doctrine don't know how to translate the string value retrieved directly from the database into the required object.

In cases where code expects the object to be of a given type and not a string I can perform the string to object translation, however it would be more elegant if this could happen automatically whenever an entity of this type is retrieved from the database.

I have a custom entity repository for this entity and have tried to override the `find()` method but this does not appear to be called.

I could modify the `getProperty()` method to translate from a string to the correct object type but this seems inelegant and ties the entity and the relevant string to object translator too closely.

Within the context of a Symfony2 project, what is the currently most-elegant best-practice means of ensuring that the given entity's property is set to the correct type when retrieved from the database?

Comment: Maybe it's related to the lazy loading of doctrine

Comment: Is the object an entity or another class altogether?

Comment: @Flosculus it is another class altogether

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a custom mapping type for this. See http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/cookbook/advanced-field-value-conversion-using-custom-mapping-types.html on how to implement them. In particular have a look at the `convertToPHPValue()` and `convertToDatabaseValue()` methods.